# how to pass parameter to a loaded view page in codeigniter via ajax

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Is there any way to pass parameter that view which is already loaded. My controller load the page with a form contain `round, batch, fromDate, toDate` then when I click to submit via ajax and post the data as parameter for the model. Also the variable I get from the model that would be pass my loaded view.

Controller:

```
public function rawAttendance(){
        $round =  $this->input->post('round',TRUE);
        $batch =  $this->input->post('batchid',TRUE);
        $fromdate =  $this->input->post('FromDate',TRUE);
        $todate =  $this->input->post('ToDate',TRUE);

        $user_data['userinfo'] = $this->logindatamodel->login_data();
        $data['round'] = $this->AttendanceModel->get_round();
        $data['IDS'] = $this->AttendanceModel->raw_attendance_TID($batch);
        $data['Dates'] = $this->AttendanceModel->raw_attendance_Data($batch);

        $this->load->view('common/header', $user_data);
        $this->load->view('common/menu', $user_data);
        $this->load->view('viewParam',$data);
        $this->load->view('attendance/rawAttendance', $data);
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }
```

Script:

```
$("#submitparam").click(function(e){  // passing down the event 
                $.ajax({
                    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/attendance/rawAttendance",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $("#param").serialize(),
                        success: function(data){
                           $("#result").html(data);
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert("Fail")
                        }
                    });
                e.preventDefault(); // could also use: return false;
                });
```

Comment: you have to load that part also in ajax if its already loaded.

Comment: could you please show me, how do I load that part in ajax? I'm totally new in ajax. please

Comment: you want to load the view which is already loaded rite?/

Comment: yes  sir. I want to load the view which is already loaded, cause I need pass the variable.

Comment: the code which you have added is not working???

Comment: this is not working yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98247/discussion-between-mir-abzal-ali-and-niranjan-n-raju).

Comment: Why is it important you reload this page with ajax? Isn't it smarter to update/replace your html through ajax where you need it? It seems to me you have 2 views that change: viewParam & attendance/rawAttendance. Return those as strings, and replace corresponding html with Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion, do following changes

You have to load what ever is required in ajax call like this.

First pass one more variable from ajax like this,

```
data: $("#param").serialize() + '&=fromAjax' + true,
```

Next in controller,

```
if($this->input->post("fromAjax"){
    $this->load->view('attendance/rawAttendance', $data);  
} else {
    $this->load->view('common/header', $user_data);
    $this->load->view('common/menu', $user_data);
    $this->load->view('viewParam',$data);
    $this->load->view('attendance/rawAttendance', $data);
    $this->load->view('common/footer');
}
```